# handle on NSNull with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I want to handle on a SwiftyJSON return value with NSNull, but I don't know how? If a timeout is reached I give back a JSON enum from SwiftyJSON with `object : NSNull()`

Here is my code:

```
    func ping(url:String) -> JSON {

    var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    var waiting = true
    var JSONresponse:JSON!

    Alamofire
        .request(.GET, myURL)
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

            JSONresponse = JSON(object: data!)
            waiting = false
    }

    while (waiting) {
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate())
        usleep(10)

        var timeout:Double = 10.0
        var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        if (elapsedTime > timeout)
        {
            waiting = false
            //JSONresponse returns NSNull() on timeout
            JSONresponse = JSON(object: NSNull())
        }
    }

  return JSONresponse
}
```

How can I parse the return value i.e. in an if-clause? If the return value is from the type `NSNull` I want to generate an error message.

THX!

Comment: Synchronous networking is a really, really bad idea. Instead of blocking to return the JSON value, have `ping()` return a completion handler.

Comment: Do you have an example for my code?